# summary shows only new memberships

Tags: civireport

I have summary report and a membership of active members report. When I look at the active members, for 2019 I get about 7 people. When I look at the summary of memberships (grouped per month) I get only 3 people. The only difference in the persons is their status. It seems only the new people are showed in the summary. However, I want to show all the people that have renewed their membership. 
I've already tried filtering the summary on status 'New' and 'Current', but that doesn't do anything